# How to change Datatables button color with Bootstrap5?

Tags: datatables

I am creating websites with Datatables plug-in.
I want to change the button color, but I don't know the methods.
It is my code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reportTable').DataTable({
       
        buttons: [
       
        'searchPanes',
        'colvis',
        {
      
            extend: 'print',
            split: [ 'pdf', 'excel','csv'],
        }
        ],
        select: {
            style:    'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        fixedHeader: true,
        columnDefs: [ { targets: [0,1,2,3,4,7,10], visible: true}, 
                      { targets: '_all', visible: false }, 
                      {
                        orderable: false,
                        className: 'select-checkbox',
                        targets:   0
                    }
                      ],
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        order: [[7, 'desc']],
        
        "dom": "<'row mb-3'<'col-6 col-md-4'l><'col-6 col-md-4 'B><'col-6 col-md-4'f>>" + 
        "<'row my-4'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>"
    });
    
});
```

It is the current button color.
[current button color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr20S.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it by extending the button and adding a `className` property.

```js
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'searchPanes',
        className: 'btn btn-danger'
    },
    {
        extend: 'colvis',
        className: 'btn btn-warning',
    },
    {
        extend: 'print',
        className: 'btn btn-success',
        split: ['pdf','excel','csv']
    }
],
```